# How to force new token/session in next-auth server-side after overriding default signOut method?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm using the credentials provider of Next-Auth, where the sign in would set the user into the token, then into the session. The set cookies is also applied.

In order to signOut, I overrode the default [signOut Method](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/events)

```
[...nextauth].ts

events: {
    async signOut({ token, session }) {
        // Delete auth cookie on signout so it doesn't persist past log out
        res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "");
    }
},
```

However, now my session doesn't refresh or destroy itself. So the cilentside still thinks I'm logged in even after calling the sign out method.

How can I force refresh the token/session in the serverside? Would it just be setting `token/session = {}` in signOut? Is there some default method that can do that?

Comment: where does `res` come from?

Comment: It comes from nextauth itself. It's kinda undocumented always exists in the events or something of that sort.

Answer (score 1):

It was like my initial thoughts, just set token/session = {}, then that would delete the session accordingly.

```
async signOut({ token, session }) {
    // Delete auth cookie on signout so it doesn't persist past log out
    res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "");

    // Set token/session to {}, that would update the cilentside token/session as well
    token = {};
    session = {};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the `signIn` callback instead?

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  callbacks: {
    signIn({ user }) {
      return user?.email === 'my-email@gmail.com';
    },
  },
};
```

Here's their documentation if you want to read further. [next-auth](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#sign-in-callback)

You can also return a string for the `signIn` callback, which will act as a redirect.